# Custom http handler in web.config

Tags: c#, web-config, httphandler

I have and IIS website which consists of just `index.html` and `web.config`. I want to override the request process based on certain conditions. Thus I found a tutorial and wrote my handler by creating a new Class Library:

```
namespace skmHttpHandlers
{
    public class SimpleHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.Write ("<html><body><h1>Test</h1></body></html>");
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I built the library and copied `skmHttpHandlers.dll` into the folder where `index.html` and `web.config` resides. Unfortunately it doesn't find my handler and shows an error:

**Could not load file or assembly 'skmHttpHandlers' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

My web.config looks like this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>          
            <add name="SimpleHandler" path="*" verb="*" 
            type="skmHttpHandlers.SimpleHandler, skmHttpHandlers" 
            resourceType="Unspecified" 
            requireAccess="Script" 
            preCondition="integratedMode" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

IIS looks up handler assembly in predefined set of directories. The directory of Web application itself is not in the list, that's why you get `FileNotFoundException`. The [suggested](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/308001/how-to-create-an-asp-net-http-handler-by-using-visual-c--net) location for the handlers is `bin` directory in the application root. So to fix the problem - create `bin` directory near `web.config` and move `skmHttpHandlers.dll` assembly in it.

In the future, when you encounter similar problems, you could [enable Fusion log](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3256753/5740031) to get detailed information where the assembly was looked up:

[image]